# Run a function immediately after a payment is made

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription, revenuecat

I am using [purchases_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter)  and [revenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) to offer a subscription on my app.

How can I run a function immediately after the payment is made?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RevenueCat, you can make any action you want after the purchase line.
Below is an example of my checkout function

```
static Future<Package?> makePurchases(Package? package, ValueNotifier<bool> isWaiting) async {
        try {
          isWaiting.value = true;
          purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(package!);
          await Purchases.syncPurchases();
          if (purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["Pro"]!.isActive) {
            purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(package);
          }
    
          // here purchase is done
          // do something
    
          isWaiting.value = false;
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          var errorCode = PurchasesErrorHelper.getErrorCode(e);
          if (errorCode != PurchasesErrorCode.purchaseCancelledError) {}
    
          isWaiting.value = false;
        }
        isWaiting.value = false;
        return null;
      }
```